# Advice Design Pattern to add multiple fees and item wise list

Tags: design-patterns

I need to write application in that I have calculation like this:

1. Basic Fee
2. Registration Fee; registration % ( basic fee) will vary based on property .
3. Sales tax; ( basic fee + Registration Fee ) %, similar based on location it will vary;
4. Service tax;( basic fee + Registration Fee + Sales Tax) %

In this I need to configure that tell us to include or not the Sales tax and service tax.
Finally I need to Item wise amounts AS Basic Fee, Registration Fee, Sales tax and Service tax.

What design pattern I have to use to achieve this?

I have confusion on Decorator and Chain-of-Responsibility. and on each thing I have to store there respective fee. at the end. need list as

```
Desc     Basic  Reg  Sales  Service  Total
------------------------------------------
Item 1   100    25   22     13       160 
Item 2   80     15   12     8        115
------------------------------------------
Total    180    40   34     25       275
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) should fits your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I have confusion on Decorator and Chain-of-Responsibility. and on each thing I have to store there respective fee. at the end. need list as

Desc  Basic  Reg Sales Service Total
Item 1   100 25  22  13 160
Item 2   80 15  12  8 115

  180 40 34 25 275

Comment: Could you explain about what you're confused? I will try to be more specific :)

Answer (score 0):

Some example. Here I'm supposing you MUST have a registration fee for a sale tax and a sale tax for a service tax.

```
interface Payable {
    public float getAmount();
}

abstract class PayableDecorator implements Payable {
    private Payable base;

    public PayableDecorator(Payable base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Payable getBase() {
        return base;
    }
}

class Fee implements Payable {
    private float value;

    public Fee(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return value;
    }
}

class RegistrationFee extends PayableDecorator {
    private float registrationPercentage;

    public RegistrationFee(Payable fee, float pct) {
        super(fee);
        registrationPercentage = pct;
    }

    public float getRegistrationPercentage() {
        return registrationPercentage();
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return getBase() * (1 + registrationPercentage);
    }
}

class SaleTax extends PayableDecorator {
    private float salePercentage;

    public SaleTax(RegistrationFee registration, float pct) {
        super(registration);
        salePercentabe = pct;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return getBase() * (1 + salePercentage);
    }
}

class SericeTax extends PayableDecorator {
    private float servicePercentage;

    public SaleTax(SaleTax registration, float pct) {
        super(registration);
        salePercentabe = pct;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return getBase() * (1 + servicePercentage);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
Payable totalTax = new ServiceTax(new SaleTax(new RegistrationFee(new Fee(100), .1), .03), .01);
```